# Android Studio stuck on macOS when doing NDK develop

Tags: android, c++, macos, android-studio, android-ndk

I am an Android NDK developer, and a newbie to macOS, I was used the Android Studio on Ubuntu before, and it works well.Now I use macOS, I find when I try to open the c or cpp files which defines the JNI method, my Android Studio will stuck, I have to wait for at least 5 minutes, you know, this project is big, but it won't take much time when I use Ubuntu.Even if it was opened successfully, when I keep it opened, Android Studio become very hard to use, sometimes I even can't type!Sometimes when I open that file, Android studio just doesn't response and I have to force quit it.

Anyway, I think my problem is something to do with the **c/cpp file support of Android studio**, Can someone have experience in this field help me? Thanks very much!

---

I wonder if it is something to do with the declaratin of JNI method, my colleague write it, uses macro:

```
#define JNI_METHOD(return_type, method_name)
    JNIEXPORT return_type JNICALL 
    Java_com_example_sometype_ClassName_##method_name

// and use it like this way
JNI_METHOD(jlong, nativeMethod)(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
// ...
}
```

---

#### System and Software info:

> Android Studio 2.2.2
>   Build #AI-145.3360264, built on October 18, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b05 x86_64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> mac OS Sierra
>   Version 10.12

#### NDK build:

I use Android.mk to build my project, and I add it in build.gradle :

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

---

*Edit 2016-10-27 :*

I found something:

I have a large header file which has 53025 lines. When Android Studio open any file included this header file, it will stuck. I think it is reason but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my question myself.

This is the truth

> I found something:
>
> I have a large header file which has 53025 lines. When Android Studio open any file included this header file, it will stuck. I think it is reason but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

This header file is the root cause and I create a source file to save this data, declare the variables in the header file.